# elementary OS PPA's

Tags: ppa

- Where can I search for elementary OS PPA's ?

  I used to search Ubuntu PPA's in [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/).
- Which version of Ubuntu PPA's can I use in  elementary OS?

  Since there are different versions and also LTS and non LTS difference in Ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the currently supported version of elementary OS (0.3 Freya) is based upon the current LTS version of Ubuntu (14.04)*, anything that works with Trusty should work just fine in elementary.

So, any app that has a PPA dedicated to Trusty on Launchpad should work as expected.

- Note that the hardware stack in 0.3.1 was actually based upon 15.04